# How to customize siriKit

Tags: ios

Is it possible to customize siriKit?. I need to open a particular view using siri, like if I said "open customerDetailsView from customer(App Name)", siri need to open particular view. Is it possible to open. Otherwise how to customize Intents UI of siriKit and how can I present my data in that Intents UI.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can send to a particular view controller in your app from Siri by following the instructions I outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40114075/open-a-different-uiviewcontroller-when-app-is-launched-via-sirikit/40430207#40430207  For Intents UI see Apple's documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Intents/Conceptual/SiriIntegrationGuide/ProvidingaCustomInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016875-CH7-SW1

Answer (score 0):

Siri can't open a particular view from app and display as an answer in Siri View. Like as per question from customer app you can't open customerDetailsView. Because siri provides a limited set of methods for each intent provided in apple documentation.
You can customize the SiriKit UI displayed to user for each particular question asked

Answer (score 0):

Check out `Introduction to Siri Shortcuts` from `WWDC18`.
`Intents Definition` can customize intents now.